# user preferences resolution

Tags: interface

The highest the resolution will go is 4, the default is 90, tried changing it but reverts back to 4,I'm using the latest blender version on a windows 10 (Home) laptop
Any ideas on how to change it back, without reinstalling blender, have tried the repair option but this has no effect.

Comment: What kind of resolution are you referring to? There are about 6 or 7 different kinds in Blender alone and none of them have any relation to eachother. SubSurf Modifier Viewport resolution? Remesh Voxel resolution? Final render output resolution? Smoke sim resolution?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Got it sorted, my mistake default is 0.90, can reset to this and all ok